Do handling of JSON-format or anti-pattern (comma-delimited values etc.) in relational database introduces performance and maintainability issues
If...
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',')
    FROM
        TABLE_NAME

introduces an anti-pattern (i.e., can cause poor performance, incorrect results (kindly verify this one), and maintainability issues of the T-SQL queries);
How about this:
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COLUMN_NAME)
    SELECT
        N'{"KEY_VALUE": [' + TBN.STR_AGG + '"]}' JSON_FORMAT_VALUE
    FROM
        (SELECT
             STRING_AGG('"' + COLUMN_NAME, + '", ') STR_AGG
         FROM
             TABLE_NAME) TBN

This is my actual test sample query:
DECLARE @users TABLE(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    username NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(50)
);

DECLARE @features TABLE(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    is_enabled BIT
);

DECLARE @feature_user TABLE(
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    feature_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @users(
    username,
    email,
    status
)
VALUES(
    N'john_doe',
    N'john_doe@example.com',
    'active'
),
(
    N'mark_daniels',
    N'mark_daniels@example.com',
    'inactive'
),
(
    N'alice_jane',
    N'alice_jane@example.com',
    'active'
);

INSERT INTO @features(
    name,
    description,
    is_enabled
)
VALUES(
    'notifications',
    'Send notifications to users',
    'TRUE'
),
(
    'csv export',
    'Export data to CSV format',
    'FALSE'
),
(
    'redesign landing page',
    'Revamp the landing page layout',
    'TRUE'
);

INSERT INTO @feature_user
VALUES(
    1,
    1
),
(
    1,
    2
),
(
    1,
    3
),
(
    2,
    1
),
(
    2,
    2
),
(
    3,
    3
)

-- Produces comma-delimited data structure
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id,
    u.username,
    u.email,
    u.status,
    STRING_AGG(f.name, ', ') AS feature_names
FROM @users u
LEFT JOIN @feature_user fu ON fu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN @features f ON fu.feature_id = f.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.email, u.status;


-- Produces denormalized data structure
SELECT  
    feature_data.user_id,
    feature_data.username,
    feature_data.email,
    feature_data.status,
    N'{"feature_data": [' + feature_data.feature_names + '"]}' feature_names
    --ADD HERE THE RECORDS THAT YOU DON'T WANT TO BE DUPLICATED ROWS, WHERE YOU NEED TO USE THE SAME APPROACH WITH feature_names
FROM(
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id,
    u.username,
    u.email,
    u.status,
    STRING_AGG('"' + f.name, + '", ') feature_names
    --ADD HERE THE RECORDS THAT YOU DON'T WANT TO BE DUPLICATED ROWS, WHERE YOU NEED TO USE THE SAME APPROACH WITH feature_names
FROM @users u
LEFT JOIN @feature_user fu ON fu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN @features f ON fu.feature_id = f.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.email, u.status) feature_data;

-- The below query to check if the JSON data is valid
SELECT  
    ISJSON(N'{"feature_data": [' + feature_data.feature_names + '"]}') feature_names
    --ADD HERE THE RECORDS THAT YOU DON'T WANT TO BE DUPLICATED ROWS, WHERE YOU NEED TO USE THE SAME APPROACH WITH feature_names
FROM(
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG('"' + f.name, + '", ') feature_names
    --ADD HERE THE RECORDS THAT YOU DON'T WANT TO BE DUPLICATED ROWS, WHERE YOU NEED TO USE THE SAME APPROACH WITH feature_names
FROM @users u
LEFT JOIN @feature_user fu ON fu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN @features f ON fu.feature_id = f.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.email, u.status) feature_data;

And the SELECT query outputs are:

Credits to the owner of the idea: How to Avoid Redundant Rows When Joining Tables in SQL?
However, this case-scenario reflects with my database setup.
Explanations: The JSON data will be decoded for later use in the SQL Server database with a compatibility level of 130 or greater, and I am using compatibility level 140 or SQL Server 2017.
The application of this idea as to relate to the given example is when concatenating data within a single property (e.g., specific column set). Which one from the given example do offer much performance efficient in terms of considering the constantly growing database.
Other than this, can somebody give a set of queries in order to avoid anti-pattern?
I want to deep dive into anti-pattern scheme, for me to really understand how it really affects queries.
UPDATE:
DECLARE @compile_table_str_agg TABLE( --denormalizing data through comma-delimited data compilation
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    username NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(50),
    feature_names VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @compile_table_json TABLE( --denormalizing data through json-structure data compilation
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    username NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(50),
    feature_names VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @compile_table_str_agg
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id,
    u.username,
    u.email,
    u.status,
    STRING_AGG(f.name, ', ') AS feature_names
FROM @users u
LEFT JOIN @feature_user fu ON fu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN @features f ON fu.feature_id = f.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.email, u.status;

INSERT INTO @compile_table_json
SELECT  
    feature_data.user_id,
    feature_data.username,
    feature_data.email,
    feature_data.status,
    N'{"feature_data": [' + feature_data.feature_names + '"]}' feature_names
    --ADD HERE THE RECORDS THAT YOU DON'T WANT TO BE DUPLICATED ROWS, WHERE YOU NEED TO USE THE SAME APPROACH WITH feature_names
FROM(
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id,
    u.username,
    u.email,
    u.status,
    STRING_AGG('"' + f.name, + '", ') feature_names
    --ADD HERE THE RECORDS THAT YOU DON'T WANT TO BE DUPLICATED ROWS, WHERE YOU NEED TO USE THE SAME APPROACH WITH feature_names
FROM @users u
LEFT JOIN @feature_user fu ON fu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN @features f ON fu.feature_id = f.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, u.email, u.status) feature_data;

-- Retrieving the compiled STRING_AGG data
SELECT
    user_id,
    username,
    email,
    status,
    ca.*
FROM
    @compile_table_str_agg str_agg1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
        com_delimited.*
    FROM
        STRING_SPLIT(
            feature_names, ',') com_delimited
) ca;

-- Retrieving the compiled JSON structure data
SELECT
    user_id,
    username,
    email,
    status,
    sa.ft_values
FROM
    @compile_table_json json1
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(json1.feature_names) WITH(
            feature_data NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.feature_data' AS JSON
        ) ca
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(ca.feature_data) WITH (ft_values NVARCHAR(25) '$') sa;

And the UPDATE, SELECT query outputs are:

CONCLUSION: Both offer the same output, but which one offers more performance or maintainability efficiency even as the database gets larger?
JSON QUERY REFERENCE:
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @json = '{"info": {"address": [{"town": "Belgrade"}, {"town": "Paris"}, {"town":"Madrid"}]}}';
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.info.address[0].town', 'Philippines');

SELECT modifiedJson = @json;

DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @json2 = N'[
  {"id": 2, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
  {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json2) WITH (
    id INT 'strict $.id',
    firstName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.name',
    lastName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.surname',
    age INT,
    dateOfBirth DATETIME2 '$.dob'
);

DECLARE @json3 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @json3 = N'[
  {"id": 3, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
  {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith", "skills": ["SQL", "C#", "Azure"]}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"},
  {"id": 1, "info": {"name": "DevQt", "surname": "PH", "skills": ["Dart", "Java", "C#", "VB", "Javascript", "SQL"]}, "age": 26, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

SELECT id,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    age,
    dateOfBirth,
    skill
FROM OPENJSON(@json3) WITH (
    id INT 'strict $.id',
    firstName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.name',
    lastName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.surname',
    age INT,
    dateOfBirth DATETIME2 '$.dob',
    skills NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.info.skills' AS JSON
)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(skills) WITH (skill NVARCHAR(15) '$')
ORDER BY id;

DECLARE @jsonVariable NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @jsonVariable = N'[
  {
    "Order": {
      "Number":"SO43659",
      "Date":"2011-05-31T00:00:00"
    },
    "AccountNumber":"AW29825",
    "Item": {
      "Price":2024.9940,
      "Quantity":1
    }
  },
  {
    "Order": {
      "Number":"SO43661",
      "Date":"2011-06-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "AccountNumber":"AW73565",
    "Item": {
      "Price":2024.9940,
      "Quantity":3
    }
  }
]';

-- INSERT INTO <sampleTable>
SELECT SalesOrderJsonData.*
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVariable, N'$') WITH (
    Number VARCHAR(200) N'$.Order.Number',
    Date DATETIME N'$.Order.Date',
    Customer VARCHAR(200) N'$.AccountNumber',
    Quantity INT N'$.Item.Quantity'
) AS SalesOrderJsonData;

And the JSON query outputs are:

Additional explanations: I've included the reference in handling JSON for the others to see my perception of embedding JSON with relational databases in SQL Server.
Original reference: JSON data in SQL Server

Do you plan to operate on the data in any way (manipulate, aggregate, join, filter, or sort on it), or is it just extra information that's being stored and recalled later on to be displayed only?


... can cause poor performance ...

Have you noticed that your queries are littered with group by constructs?
That's a potential performance hit right there, having to process all the relevant records and then "removing" the duplicates.  It's better not to store duplicates in the first place.
Also, it seems to me that your database is having to do a potentially significant amount of work just to get the data back into the "shape" that it ought to be in to start with.  That's a performance hit, right there.

... can cause ... incorrect results ...

I think you may have missed that your first 'update'd query returns incorrect values.  Rows 2, 3 & 5 all appear to have a leading space on them!  (Consider this "kindly verified".)
And if you ever need to query this data for a specific feature, you can forget about any indexes.  Your database will have to Table Scan.
After all, how would you determine if a given value appears in an aggregated field?
Given:
select feature_values 
from ... 

+------------------------------------------------+
| feature_values                                 |
+------------------------------------------------+
| notifications,csv export,redesign landing page |
+------------------------------------------------+

select feature_values 
from ... 
where features_values like '%,csv export,%' 

... would work but ...
select feature_values 
from ... 
where features_values like '%,notifications,%' 

... would not!
(You cannot use like '%notifications%' because someone [else] might add another feature that includes this word (say, "email notifications") later on!)
As for overall performance, we cannot tell you.
Test your scenario and see how it works but I suspect it will start to slow down significantly as your data expands.
